# How to join two tables and convert joined table to a vector layer containing points in QGIS?

Tags: qgis, convert, attribute-table, attribute-joins

I have one table that contains 450 locations and a table that has 10'000 rows containing data and no spatial information. I have a column that allows me to join them. The issue is that I want to have the joinig to take place by having my data table as main table. Therefore the solution of using the data table and converting it to a shape data and joining it with my data layer is not an option since it creates a file with only 450 rows and which obviously was not the intended result. What would be the solution to this problem.

Comment: Are they both shapefiles or just the one containing the 450 locations?

Comment: They are both actually .csv files. And the location file has it's coordinates in the famous x, y format in seperate columns.

Comment: What you're trying to do is called a one-to-many join. Both QGIS and ArcGIS have challenges when trying to do this. It sounds like QGIS did the same thing Arc would - returned first matching record and that's it. The question I've flagged this as a duplicate of should help you on the QGIS side. Note there are different ways to handle this - either as a relate or with duplicate geometry. You could join the other way in a regular database and then create points from the xy for duplicate geometry - it's not clear what your end goal is (ie, how many points).

Comment: My final objective was to obtain 10'000 rows containing respective locations after the merge. In theory the linking feature works. It is just that when for example generating text diagrams I cannot chose the attributes of the huge data table as a option for visualization.

Comment: Ok has worked as intended thank you Chris W and Joseph. It was indeed what I wanted to do. The joining feature however is very slow. I might suggest the usage of excel Vlookup or access query to do it and then feed the table to QGIS rather than to do it in the application directly.

Comment: Thanks @ChrisW, interesting to see the other various methods.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your question correctly, you could try the following:

- Add the .csv file with the 450 locations layer as a *Delimited Text Layer* and select the appropriate options
- Add the other .csv file again as a *Delimited Text Layer* but select the **No geometry (attribute only table)** option

From the **Processing** plugin, select the *Join attributes table* algorithm, add both layers as the Input layers and select the same Column that both layers have as the Table field. [image: Join attributes table]

NB: I haven't tested this method on .csv files but it may still work.

Comment: It seems like it might be the sollution but QGIS is sadly stops to respond when I try to do this.